# Какую форму сказуемого выбрать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, выбор-варианта, аббревиатуры

*От профессионализма, самоотдачи и ответственности работников мсу во многом завис**и**т социальное самочувствие населения, его доверие к власти.*
Или завис**я**т?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что нужно написать так:
*От профессионализма, самоотдачи и ответственности работников **МСУ** во многом **зависят** социальное самочувствие населения, его доверие к власти.*

*Зависят* — сказуемое, *самочувствие, доверие* — однородные подлежащие.
Обычно при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) употребляется форма единственного числа (такая же форма предпочтительна и при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих).
Однако **в деловой речи** (куда мы смело можем отнести это предложение) предпочитается форма множественного числа, например:
*На пушной аукцион были **выставлены** каракуль и лисьи шкурки.

**Строятся** завод, электростанция и несколько комплексов.*

[МСУ](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9C%D0%A1%D0%A3) (местное самоуправление) — это аббревиатура, пишется заглавными буквами.

[Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-190-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-odnorodnymi-podlezhashchimi)
[Значения аббревиатуры МСУ](https://xn----7sbbfsshef0aedydgg4lyb.xn--p1ai/a/%D0%9C%D0%A1%D0%A3)

Answer (score 4):

Выбранный вариант связи двух понятий (через запятую) указывает на то, что говорящий считает их взаимосвязанными: второе понятие играет *подчиненную* смысловую роль, *дополняя* (подразумевается "а также") или *уточняя* ("а следовательно" или "в частности") первое - иначе они *были бы связаны союзом "и"*. Поэтому глагол, на мой взгляд, естественнее отнести к первому упомянутому, "ведущему" понятию ("социальное самочувствие населения"), т. е. употребить его в **единственном** числе.